# How to manage multiple configuration consistently in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a large VisualStudio solution with multiple projects.
So far it supports Debug|Win32, Debug|x64, Release|Win32, Release|x64, ReleaseLog|Win32, ReleaseLog|x64, (ReleaseLog is similar to Release but with logging turned on).

I'd like to add a new config type, similar to Release but only one compilation flag changes.
I'd like avoiding creating whole new section of Configuration in each vcxproj that are "duplicate" of Release configuration, and most importantly I want to be sure that beside this one compilation flag everything else will be exactly the same.

How can I achieve ?

Can we make a Configuration inheriting from another one ?

Comment: Have a look at property sheets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-170

Comment: Was your problem solved?  Props file is also one approach.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT no.
So far the only answers I got described "copying" instead of "inheriting". Can you please share documentation ?
Note that I'm familiar with props files. I already use some to share common settings between projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit release through configuration manger -> new solution configuration and check create project configuration.

Comment: It makes a copy of the configuration. It doesn't inehrit.